# Error in Connectivity with MySql in PHP even though server is running and MySql is installed

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I am trying connectivity with mysql in php. But it shows an error message at this line

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqli_connect() in
>   C:\wamp64\www\webapp\init.php on line 6

Here is my code..

```
<?php
$db_name="webappdp";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";
$con=sqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
if(!$con)
{
    echo "Connection error...".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo"<h3>Database Connection Success</h3>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can I suggest you start by reading the PHP Manual, specifically [the mysqli_ section](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 2):

function name is `mysqli_connect()` not `sqli_connect`

Put this line
   `$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);`

Comment: Thanks it's working now